# Swift: NSAttributedString & emojis

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, emoji, nsrange

I use a `UITextView` with text attributes editing enabled and I am having issue with getting the attributes when there are emojis in the text.

Here is the code I use:

```swift
var textAttributes = [(attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], range: NSRange)]()
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: textView.attributedText.length)
textView.attributedText.enumerateAttributes(in: range) { dict, range, _ in
    textAttributes.append((attributes: dict, range: range))
}

for attribute in textAttributes {
    if let swiftRange = Range(attribute.range, in: textView.text) {
        print("NSRange \(attribute.range): \(textView.text![swiftRange])")
    } else {
        print("NSRange \(attribute.range): cannot convert to Swift range")
    }
}
```

And when I try it with a text like "Sample text ❤️", here is the output:

> NSRange {0, 12}: Sample text
>
> NSRange {12, 1}: cannot convert to Swift range
>
> NSRange {13, 1}: cannot convert to Swift range

So as you can see, I cannot get the text with the emoji in it.

The text attributes are set by my custom `NSTextStorage` applied on the text view. Here is the `setAttributes` method:

```swift
override func setAttributes(_ attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]?, range: NSRange) {
    guard (range.location + range.length - 1) < string.count  else {
        print("Range out of bounds")
        return
    }

    beginEditing()
    storage.setAttributes(attrs, range: range)
    edited(.editedAttributes, range: range, changeInLength: 0)
    endEditing()
}
```

Note that during editing my text view, I have some "Range out of bounds" prints.

Is there a way to convert the `NSRange` to a valid Swift `Range`?

Comment: *"Is there a way to convert the NSRange to a valid Swift Range?"* - you are doing that with `Range(attribute.range, in: textView.text)`.

Comment: `guard (range.location + range.length - 1) < string.count  else {` needs to be `guard (range.location + range.length - 1) < string.utf16.count  else {`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, the `string.utf16.count` worked! However, the conversion to Swift `Range` still write "cannot convert to Swift range". I succeeded to substring with `textView.attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: attribute.range).string`

Comment: Somewhere you have an `NSRange` that is probably based on a Swift `String` count and that is wrong. It must always be `.utf16.count` when creating an `NSRange` from a `String`. So again, show how you apply the attributes to the attributed text (and show how you create the ranges).

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed all my `.count` to `.utf16.count` in `NSRange` and it works as expected!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most important thing to remember when working with `NSAttributedString`, `NSRange`, and `String` is that `NSAttributedString` (and `NSString`) and `NSRange` are based on UTF-16 encoded lengths. But `String` and its `count` are based on actual character counts. They don't mix.

If you ever try to create an `NSRange` with `someSwiftString.count`, you will get the wrong range. Always use `someSwiftString.utf16.count`.

In your specific case you are applying attributes to half for the ❤️ character due to the wrong length in the `NSRange` and that cascades to the errors you see.

And in the code you posted, you need to change:

```
guard (range.location + range.length - 1) < string.count else {
```

to:

```
guard (range.location + range.length - 1) < string.utf16.count else {
```

for the same reasons described above.

Comment: Excellent ! it helped me today.